# Ruby 2.1+ Keyword Arguments Initializers Syntax

Tags: ruby

Sandi Metz in Practical Object-Oriented Design in Ruby has this example on page 47:

```
class Gear
    attr_reader :chainring, :cog, :wheel
    def initialize(args)
        @chainring = args[:chainring]
        @cog       = args[:cog]
        @wheel     = args[:wheel]
    end
    ...
end
```

In Ruby 2.1+ can the same be expressed as:

```
class Gear
    attr_reader :chainring, :cog, :wheel
    def initialize(chainring:, cog:, wheel:)
        @chainring = chainring
        @cog       = cog
        @wheel     = wheel
    end
    ...
end
```

Would these two be equivalent? They do seem to work in the same manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first method, any extra keys in the `args` hash will be ignored, and if any of the three specified are missing the appropriate variable will be assigned `nil`. In the second method, any additional or missing arguments will produce an `ArgumentError` exception.

Answer (score 0):

In the first method, You need to pass a hash so it takes the values from the keys and if the keys are not present, it assigns `nil`

```
[42] pry(main)> Gear.new({:cog => 1})
=> #<Gear:0xb9d36bc @chainring=nil, @cog=1, @wheel=nil>
```

In the second method you need to pass exact number of arguments. If you pass any extra arguments you get the `ArgumentError`

```
[38] pry(main)> class Gear
[38] pry(main)*   attr_reader :chainring, :cog, :wheel    
[38] pry(main)*   def initialize(args)    
[38] pry(main)*     @chainring = args[:chainring]        
[38] pry(main)*     @cog       = args[:cog]        
[38] pry(main)*     @wheel     = args[:wheel]        
[38] pry(main)*   end      
[38] pry(main)*   ...    
Error: there was a problem executing system command: ..
[38] pry(main)* end  
=> :initialize
[39] pry(main)> Gear.new(1,2,3,4,5,)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (5 for 1)
from (pry):38:in `initialize'
```